# tkinter python multiple Scrollbars in Notebook widget

Tags: macos, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, tk-toolkit

I'm using Python 3.2.3 and Tkinter (8.5.11) on Mac OS 10.7. I have set up a Tkk Notebook widget with several tabs. On the first three frames, there are Listboxes with Scrollbars synched to them. Each of the Scrollbars works fine, but if I manipulate the last of the three created, the other two become unresponsive. (The same thing happened when there were Scrollbars on only two of the panes—-using the Scrollbar on the first pane didn't affect the second pane's Scrollbar, but using the second pane's Scrollbar froze the first pane's). I'm attaching the code below; this looks pretty straightforward to me, but I'm new at this.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def switchTab():
    newTab=tabList[1]
    fieldbook.select(tab_id=newTab)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1000x700+1000+40')
root.resizable(FALSE,FALSE)
root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.title("Electronic Fieldbook")

fieldbook = ttk.Notebook(root)
f1 = ttk.Frame(fieldbook);
f2 = ttk.Frame(fieldbook);
f3 = ttk.Frame(fieldbook);
f4 = ttk.Frame(fieldbook);
f5 = ttk.Frame(fieldbook);
f6 = ttk.Frame(fieldbook);
f7 = ttk.Frame(fieldbook);
f8 = ttk.Frame(fieldbook);
f9 = ttk.Frame(fieldbook);
fieldbook.add(f1, text="Home")
fieldbook.add(f2, text="Lexicon")
fieldbook.add(f3, text="Texts")
fieldbook.add(f4, text="Examples")
fieldbook.add(f5, text="Datasets")
fieldbook.add(f6, text="Concordances")
fieldbook.add(f7, text="Paradigms")
fieldbook.add(f8, text="Abbreviations")
fieldbook.add(f9, text="Index")

##create tabs

homeLabel=ttk.Label(f1, text="Lhome")
lexiconLabel=ttk.Label(f2, text="Llexicon")
textsLabel=ttk.Label(f3, text="Ltexts")
examplesLabel=ttk.Label(f4, text="Lexamples")
datasetsLabel=ttk.Label(f5, text="Ldatasets")
concordancesLabel=ttk.Label(f6, text="Lconcordances")
paradigmsLabel=ttk.Label(f7, text="Lparadigms")
abbrvLabel=ttk.Label(f8, text="Labbreviations")
indexLabel=ttk.Label(f9, text="Lindex")

##create home widgets
lexBox = Listbox(f1, height = 32)
lexScrl = ttk.Scrollbar(f1, orient=VERTICAL, command=lexBox.yview)
LexHomeLabel = ttk.Label(f1, text="Lexicon")
testButton = ttk.Button(f1, text="Test", command=switchTab)

##create Lexicon widgets
navBox = Listbox(f2, height = 35)
navScrl = ttk.Scrollbar(f2, orient=VERTICAL, command=navBox.yview)

##create Text widgets
txtBox = Listbox(f3, height = 35)
txtScrl = ttk.Scrollbar(f3, orient=VERTICAL, command=txtBox.yview)

##grid widgets
fieldbook.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(N,W,S,E))

## grid home widgets
LexHomeLabel.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=(N))
lexBox.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(N,W,S,E))
for i in range(1,101):
    lexBox.insert('end', 'Line %d of 100' % i)
lexScrl.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=(N,S))
lexBox['yscrollcommand'] = lexScrl.set
testButton.grid(column=3, row= 2, sticky=(S,E))

##grid lexicon widgets
navBox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(N,W,S,E))
for i in lexBox.get(0, 'end'):
    navBox.insert('end', i)
navScrl.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky=(N,S))
navBox['yscrollcommand'] = navScrl.set

##grid txt widgets
txtBox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(N,W,S,E))
for i in range(1,101):
    txtBox.insert('end', 'Text %d of 100' % i)
txtScrl.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky=(N,S))
txtBox['yscrollcommand'] = txtScrl.set

tabList = fieldbook.tabs()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oddly, when the scrollbar in the first tab appears dead, it's actually scrolling the contents of the third tab. In all my years of Tk programming I've never seen this sort of bug. I'm seeing this on OSX with python 2.7.1, and I see it even if I use tk.Scrollbar rather than ttk.Scrollbar. I'm going to add the "tk" tag to maybe get a larger audience.

Comment: Not reproducable on my computer running Ubuntu Linux 12.04 .
I think this is a bug in Tk in Mac OSX.

Comment: No issue on redhat 5 using Python 3.3.0 and GTK 8.5. Could you try on another platform?

Comment: Python 3.3.0 on windows 7 works fine...

Comment: Still appears to be a problem; OS X 10.10.3 with Python 3.4.3 and the behavior is just as @BryanOakley described nearly 3 years ago.